# How to animate controls in vb .net

Tags: vb.net

I saw a video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsA5c_XIzWc

Basically, in this video I saw controls flying into the form!

He used vb .net

Could anyone explain the code used to make the control fly in, please?

Comment: You go to Google.com, and search for "vb.net animate controls", then if you get stuck with the code, ask again.

Comment: `How did he make the controls fly in?` I would assume with ***coooodzzz***. I am voting to close this as we are ***not here to program this for you***.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be anything specific about programming. Asking us `How do you do it` is not acceptable here as we do not condone writing a program for you, but rather helping on a specific issue you may be having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some improvised way on how to make controls fly into the form. You can use the **SetBounds()**.

You can take the control out of the form view by dragging it out. After that, you will going to take the coordinates. If you want to fly in "left" and "right" then you will probably need the X coords of the control. Iterate through it until it reaches the exact coordinate where you want it to be. Like for example:

I drag a Panel control at form location: **(43,76)** which is **X is 43** and **Y is 76**.

My form size is 300x300, so In this case I can simply put the control or drag the control to (301,76) which will obviously hide the control from view.

So, I want the control to get back to it's original X which is 43. What I'll do is set up a timer and set it's interval to 1ms and every time that timer ticks, it will use the SetBounds() method to decrement the X value until it reaches to 43 which will move the control.

Take a look at this code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick


            'Check if the Panel has the X coordinates less than or equal to 43. 
        If Panel1.Location.X > 43 Then
            'Use the SetBounds()
            Panel1.SetBounds(Panel1.Location.X - 1, Panel1.Location.Y, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
        Else
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

The control I'm moving is called **Panel1**. My form size is **300x300** and the initial location of Panel1 is at **(301,76)**. I want the control to move to **(43,76)**. In this case, we are going to subtract 1 from the X coordinate every time the timer ticks until it gets to **X:43**.

You can experiment on this by your own, and I use this only on my projects to add some spin offs. But use it as your own, in regards of the performance, I don't know but as long as the method doesn't block the processing of your program it should be fine.

Comment: Please do not feed these types of questions, it will only motivate others to continue the trend.

Comment: Yes I'm so sorry I just want to share my idea about it but anyway I get your point not to spoil these kind of questions. I won't do it again. Thank you.